# 'ngbd-accordion-basic' is not a known element:

Tags: angular

Im trying to add a simple accordian to an Angular app and having issues. Im not sure what and where to import .

Error i get is

```
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngbAccordion"
```

Thanks

Comment: In the `app.module` metadata, does `imports` include `NgbModule`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply import the Accordion on the module that requires its usage.

On your sample.module.ts, import **only** the Accordion module (Don't import the entire NgBootstrap module, as this will greatly increase your overall bundle size), and include it on your imports under `@NgModule` too.

```
import { NgbAccordionModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

.
.

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgbAccordionModule
    .
    .
    // others
```

After which, you can start using it.

On your component.html,

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion">
  <ngb-panel id="toggle-1" title="First panel">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>

    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
  <ngb-panel id="toggle-2" title="Second">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>

    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

You may refer to the API documentation and more examples over [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.